# How can I get rid of certain columns and write it out to another file with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My file, peaks_ee is a text file which looks like:

```
label dataset sw sf
1H 1H_2
NOESY_F1eF2e.nv
4807.69238281 4803.07373047
600.402832031 600.402832031
1H.L 1H.P 1H.W 1H.B 1H.E 1H.J 1H.U 1H_2.L 1H_2.P 1H_2.W 1H_2.B 1H_2.E 1H_2.J 1H_2.U vol int stat comment flag0 flag8 flag9
0 {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
1 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
2 {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
3 {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
4 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H1'} 5.90291 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
5 {2.H1'} 5.90291 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
6 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
7 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
8 {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
9 {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
```

My code is supposed to take the 1st, 2nd, 8th, and 9th columns and write them out to a text file. But I want the 1st and 8th columns combined, and the 2nd and 9th columns combined into one column and then I want all the duplicates removed. I also want to add a third column and have it just output "0.03" on every row.

This is the current code:

```
import pandas as pd

result={}
df = pd.read_csv("peaks_ee.xpk", sep=" ", skiprows=5)

shift1 = df["1H.P"]
shift2 = df["1H_2.P"]

mask = ((shift1>5.1) & (shift1<6)) & ((shift2>7) & (shift2<8.25))

result = df[mask]
result = result[["1H.L","1H.P","1H_2.L","1H_2.P"]]

for col in result.columns:
    if col == ("1H.L") or col==( "1H_2.L"):
         result[col]=result[col].str.strip("{} ")

res = pd.lreshape(df, {'atom_name':['1H.L','1H_2.L'], 'ppm':['1H.P','1H_2.P']}).drop_duplicates()
res['new']=0.3

result.drop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True)

tclust_atom=open("tclust_ppm.txt","w+")

res.to_string(tclust_atom, header=False)

tclust_atom.close()
```

I would like my desired output to look like:

```
1.H1'  5.82020 0.3
2.H8  7.61004 0.3  
1.H8  8.13712 0.3
2.H1'  5.90291 0.3   
4.H1'  5.74125 0.3   
3.H6  7.53261 0.3
3.H1'  5.54935 0.3   
4.H8  7.49932 0.3
3.H1'  5.54935 0.3  
3.H6  7.53261 0.3 
6.H1'  5.54297 0.3   
5.H6  7.72158 0.3
```

But currently with this code, my output is:

```
0    0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0   {1.H1'}  5.82020  0.3
1    0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0    {2.H8}  7.61004  0.3
2    0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0    {1.H8}  8.13712  0.3
5    0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0   {2.H1'}  5.90291  0.3
10   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0    {3.H6}  7.53261  0.3
11   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0   {4.H1'}  5.74125  0.3
12   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0   {3.H1'}  5.54935  0.3
13   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0    {4.H8}  7.49932  0.3
26   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0    {5.H6}  7.72158  0.3
27   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0   {6.H1'}  5.54297  0.3
```

The last three columns is what I want, but how can I get rid of the other columns and in the column which looks like:

```
{1.H1'}  
{2.H8}   
{1.H8}  
{2.H1'}  
{4.H1'}    
{3.H6}  
{3.H1'}    
{4.H8}  
{3.H1'}    
{3.H6}   
{6.H1'}     
{5.H6}
```

How can I get rid of the curly braces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method

```
df = pd.read_csv("peaks_ee.xpk", sep=" ", skiprows=5)

#Create two dataframes with desired rows, by column    
df1 = df.copy()[['1H.L','1H.P']]
df2 = df.copy()[['1H_2.L','1H_2.P']]

#retain same names
df2.rename(columns={'1H_2.L' : '1H.L', '1H_2.P' : '1H.P'},inplace=True)

#stack dataframes
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])

# Conditionally delete
df = df[(df['1H.P'] <= 6) & (df['1H.P'] >= 5)]

#Remove Curly Braces
df['1H.L'] = df['1H.L'].apply(lambda row: row.strip('{}'))

#Add column of 0.3
df['new'] = 0.3

#Drop duplicates
df.drop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! How would i write this out to another text file? Can I still use `result.to_string(tclust_atom,header=False)` ? How can I test out your code?

Comment: you can use `df.to_csv('peaks_ee2.xpk,sep=" ",index=False)`, you can also print the dataframe to inspect

Comment: Thanks again! One last question, if I didn't want my output to include the first line which is `1H.L 1H.P new` how could i do that? i.e.: I want the output to start with `1H.1' 5.8202 0.3 ` ... etc how could i do that?

Comment: Sure add header= False as in argument to read csv. The answer to these questions can be found in the (docs)[https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html].

Comment: @djk4763 how can I still filter the values to be in a certain range? for example, my second column in my desired output is a list of values, but I only want to write out the ones that are in a specific range, for example, between 5 and 6

Comment: thanks! and if it needed to be EITHER between 5 and 6 OR between 7 and 8, would the code be `df = df[(df['1H.P'] <= 6) and (df['1H.P'] >= 5)] or df[(df['1H.P'] <= 8) and (df['1H.P'] >= 7)]`

Comment: I receive an error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filter.py", line 62, in <module>
    df = df[(df['1H.P']<=5) and (df['1H.P']>=3)]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.20.3-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/pandas/core/generic.py", line 955, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` once I type in your code

Comment: you did not type it in correctly, you changed the `&` to `and`